# Reading http content from POST in MVC 4 WebApi

Tags: asp.net, post, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC 4 application, using WebApi. An external client is POST'ing to it, and I need to collect that data. I can get model binding to work with

```
public void Post([FromBody] Alert alert) { ... }
```

where Alert is a class defining the complex type. However, I have a case where I want to read whatever is in the body, even when I don't know what the structure is. So how do I read the raw header and body of the incoming POST request. I tried with this:

```
public void Post(HttpContent content) { ... }
```

but when POST'ing to the service, the Post method does not get invoked at all.

Input?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding HttpRequestMessage instead of HttpContent. That should work and will give you access to the request headers and the body.

```
public void Post(HttpRequestMessage request) { ... }
```

You can also access the Request property on your controller which should be set correctly:

```
public void Post() { var content = Request.Content; }
```